# C# .NET StreamReader() returning literal length of buffer as a string instead of actual stream data

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I'm not even sure how to adequately describe this problem.  In reading a stream, the text string I am building in chunks is just the literal length of the buffer, over and over again.

```
string json = "";

context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)) {

    while (inputStream.Peek() >= 0) {

        char[] buffer = new char[4096];

        json += inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        System.Console.WriteLine(jsonInput.Length);

    }

}

// json = "40964096409640964096 ... 4096"
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You're printing the `jsonInput` variable, which isn't mentioned in your posted code.

Comment: StreamReader has a `ReadToEnd` method. Why are you using a while loop and pushing into a buffer over and over?

Comment: This seems to do it.

                        `while (inputStream.Peek() >= 0) {

                            char[] buffer = new char[4096];

                            inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            jsonInput += new string(buffer);

                            System.Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buffer));

                        }`

Comment: Yes. But you should a) understand why; b) think about how you could have discovered the solution for yourself. In particular, you're appending the return value of `inputStream.Read` to `json`. Did you check the documentation for `StreamReader.Read` to see what the return value is?

Comment: I did discover it myself.  inputStream.Read() doesn't return data.  It puts data in the buffer.  As soon as I realised that, I had it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` returns the *number of bytes read from the stream*, which is 4096 as long as there's data available. The `+` operator on string in `json += ...` does an implicit conversion to string, so what you're summing up in the `json` variable is really a concatenation of the buffer length. What you want to do is to concatenate the buffer instead, eg with

```cs
int dataRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
json += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, dataRead);
```

Comment: What I cam up with was to use: `inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`, and then `jsonInput += new string(buffer)`;

Comment: Pretty much what you suggested.

Comment: @KWallace May work, but you might get extra data if the last packet is not complete. Also, yours will fail if you need another encoding, such as UTF8.